# Elements inside a 100% width/ 100% height landing page

Tags: html, css

I hope this isn't too confusing, but essentially it's more a question that a code deciphering.

I'd like my web page landing page to be 100% width and 100% height of any browser that the user opens it on. I already know how to do this through this code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #101010;
}
```

However, when I start to add elements within the wrapper class, and resize the browser upwards from the bottom, some of these elements drop off the main wrapper and sit below in to the next section.

My question is, if you are wanting to design a landing page with elements within a wrapper that is always 100% width and 100% height of the browser - with the elements always staying within that wrapper - is this possible through CSS alone? Would the elements need to be positioned using percentages instead of pixel denotations, or would this require JavaScript to enable this?

Comment: well it should be possible but it depends very much on the layout you want and the type of content (image, text...)

Comment: Well, I'd be looking to add fairly large text through a H1 tag, and then a downarrow image that is vertically middle aligned to the bottom of the wrapper. I'm just wondering if everything was set to percentages to respond to a browser size it would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need percentages and `absolute` or `fixed` positioning with `top` or/and `bottom` and `left` and/or `right` values, don't use `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` because they are calculated on window width and therefore won't adapt to window height.

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

For images, you can use `max-height` and `max-width` with percentage with `height:auto;` and `width:auto;` so they never overflow container.

The other issue will be the text especialy if it is huge because you won't be able to adapt the font-size to the height of window only with css. You will need JS to retrieve window height and change the font-size.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yTA7m/4/)** example

Comment: Cheers chado! Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what chadocat mentioned, you will probably need to set the viewport meta tag, something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

This defines that the width of the viewport will be the same as the device you are viewing the website on. The scale of the website will be set to 100%.

And instead of percentage and viewport, CSS3 has its way that you can set the element width and height by vw and vh units, e.g.

```
width: 50vw;
```

would set the width of the element to 50% of the viewport.